# How to call a user define method in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing wepapi service.Below is my code.

```
[ActionName("getdata")]
[HttpGet]
public string getdata(string Phoneno, int servicetypeID)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString);
    string SQL = " EXEC [dbo].[GET_OperatorCircles] @Prefix,@ServiceTypeID ";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);

    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prefix", Phoneno);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceTypeID", servicetypeID);
    con.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(ds);


    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);

    return json;
}


[ActionName("getjsondata")]
[HttpGet]
public string getjsondata(string Phoneno, int servicetypeID)
{




    return json;
}
```

Actually what happend is in the above code I have two different methods but parametes are same.whenever I am calling getdata method,I am getting below response.

```
>An error has occurred.Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
getdata on type WebApi.Controllers.ValuesController
getjsondata on type WebApi.Controllers.ValuesControllerSystem.InvalidOperationException   at
```

then how to call userdefine method in webapi.

Comment: @Webruster please see my code.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling the method?
It looks like you are missing the `id` parameter in your request.
You can either add that to your request or make it "optional":

```
public string getjsondata(string Phoneno, int servicetypeID, int? id)
{
   if (!id.HasValue) { /* do something */ }
   // ....
}
```

BUT it seems you are not using it anyway, so maybe just remove it?

```
public string getjsondata(string Phoneno, int servicetypeID)
```

Comment: http://localhost:23456/api/values/getdata?Phoneno=23456789&servicetypeID=1.this way I am calling

Comment: @AnilKumar: As suspected no `id` parameter - either use e.g. `http://localhost:23456/api/values/getjsondata?Phoneno=23456789&servicetypeID=1&id=1` or remove it as it is not used anyhow...

Comment: ok id not used.what my problem is Iam calling getdata method.that method Iam placing two parameters only

Comment: ok. I removed id parameter.  then I run the program I am getting error like this ."An error has occurred.Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
getdata on type WebApi.Controllers.ValuesController
getjsondata on type WebApi.Controllers.ValuesControllerSystem.InvalidOperationException   at

Comment: any attributes define in the above method?please tell me

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? At the moment your example does not make much sense to me, as both methods do the same...

Comment: What I am doing is,I am define two different method names but parameters are same.what my intention is I am calling one method.for example getdata method. you are  not see my above code they are samples only.I want to call getdata method.how to call

Comment: Sorry, small oversight on my side: You need to omit the "get" so try calling `http://localhost:23456/api/values/data?Phoneno=23456789&servicetypeID=1`...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web Api 2, you could just define your routes using [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). This will allow you to explicitly define routes for your Api and so the signature will not be an issue, i.e you could have something like this.

```
/api/myControllerPrefix/data
/api/myControllerPrefix/jsonData
```